# Django & bad Oracle connection credentials

Tags: django, oracle

I have a Django program that is connecting to an Oracle database. In my `settings.py` file I have this configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'xe',
    'USER': 'MY_USER_NAME',
    'PASSWORD': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'HOST': 'db_server.example.com',
    'PORT': '1234',
  }
}
```

I received a strange error when attempting to load the website:

`ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error`

After further investigation, I sniffed the TCP traffic between the webserver and the database server. I discovered this text in the network communication, which I reformatted for this post:

```
(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=1.2.3.4)
        (PORT=1234)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SID=xe)
        (CID=
            (PROGRAM=httpd@webserver_hostname)
            (HOST=webserver_hostname)
            (USER=apache)
        )
    )
)
```

So my question is: why is Django attempting to connect to the Oracle database with different credentials than the ones I specified? Notably, it is attempting to use user 'apache' instead of 'MY_USER_NAME'. The database host IP, port, and SID are correct and what I specified. It just appears to be the user name that is different.

(As a side note, I suppose the password is transmitted separately in a later portion of the log in process?)

Comment: That doesn't (despite the poor choice of `USER`) mean that the application is trying to log in as the database user `apache`.  If the problem was that an incorrect username was being passed in, you'd get a very different error.  Are you trying to connect to an Oracle XE database on your local machine? Or on a remote machine? Can you connect using SQL*Plus on the same machine where your Django application is running?

Comment: @JustinCave, I am connecting to a remote machine from the web server. I installed SQL Developer on the web server and was able to successfully connect to the database.

Comment: Are you certain that the host and port you're specifying are identical to the connection you are specifying in SQL Developer?  In particular, the port would almost always be 1521.  Do you know whether Django in this case is using a thin JDBC driver to connect or whether it is using the Oracle client libraries?  My (admittedly quick) reading of the documentation seems to imply that it is using the Oracle client proper not a thin JDBC driver.  Can you connect to the remote database using SQL*Plus?

Comment: I am certain that the host and port are correct. I have changed them in this post for security, but verified they are the same. Our DBA has set the port to a non-default. Django is using Oracle Instant Client and cx_Oracle to connect. I've never installed or used SQL*Plus but can look into it if you think it would provide greater insight.

Comment: My guess if SQL Developer is working that something is misconfigured in the Oracle Instant Client install (or that the Instant Client isn't compatible with `cx_Oracle`) so having something else like SQL*Plus that could be used to test the Instant Client install would be helpful.

Comment: The only "configuration" I did for Oracle Instant Client was to set a shared object path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and run ldconfig. (Which is essentially the same as setting LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG.) Are there any other configuration steps that are necessary? I figured all the needed information would be specified in `settings.py`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23347/discussion-between-dylan-klomparens-and-justin-cave)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the full Oracle client (with Administrator tools) seems to have solved the problem. There are some nuances to take care of though:

`wsgi.py` **requires the location of ORACLE_HOME**, as it is not passed in from the shell. In my case, this is what `wsgi.py` looks like:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = '/client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In Oracle 11.2.0 client there is a bug with the library linking. To fix Oracle library linking:

1. Navigate to $ORACLE_HOME/lib (in my case, /client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db/lib/)
2. Remove file libexpat.so.1
3. As user oracle: create a symbolic link: libexpat.so.1 --> libexpat.so.1.5.2

Additionally, it is important to have the Linux loader set up properly. (Note: this is equivalent to setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I think the following is a cleaner solution). Create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` with a single line entry to the Oracle Home **library** path. In my case, it's `/client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db/lib`. Then run `ldconfig`. To verify that the loader is configured correctly you can check the shared object paths for cx_Oracle:

To find the file: as superuser, execute `updatedb` and then `locate cx_Oracle.so | grep cx_Oracle\.so$`

To test the file: `ldd <path>`

The output should look similar to this (below). **If you see the phrase "not found" then something is wrong with the loader paths.**

```
# ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb775c000)
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => /client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0xb5a25000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0xb588e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5873000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb56c2000)
    libnnz11.so => /client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db/lib/libnnz11.so (0xb5474000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb546f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb5444000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0xb5429000)
    libaio.so.1 => /lib/libaio.so.1 (0xb5427000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0xb5422000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x487b9000)
```

For convenience, you'll probably also want to create the file `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh` with these contents (note, change ORACLE_HOME to your specific install path):

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/client/oracle/product/11.2.0/db
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

Reboot for these global environment variables to take effect.

After that, Oracle connections should work in any scenario. I hope this information helps others who've had trouble with Oracle!